# How would you know if you could read/write from a port in any electronic device?

Tags: communication, cables

It's probably not the right forum to ask but this was the best one I could think of. If you know of a better forum let me know. Maybe raspberry pi or Arduino?

It's very long winded what I'm trying to figure out. In theory I would be interested in trying to capture the audio and video of any "contained electronic system" but I'm trying to understand what's possible and what's not.

I'll use the example of a DS Lite.[image] In the DS Lite, there are 4 "ports" or "access points" that are available- The DS game slot at the top, the Gameboy slot on the bottom, the headphone jack at the bottom, and the charging port at the top.

For both the DS game slot and the Gameboy slot, data seems to only go one way - into the DS lite. For the charging port, electricity only goes in but otherwise data can't seem to be carried. For the headphone jack, data seems to go out to the headphones, not in. But it's only audio data. In theory that can be intercepted.

Interestingly, in a modern cell phone, the same USB C cable that you use to charge can also be used to transfer data in and out of the cellphone.

So what I'm trying to find out is if through any of the 3 remaining ports, can data be transferred out to a computer as some sort of binary file? At the end of the day, all I need is what's displayed on the screen and the audio information. All of this is just binary - ones and zeros. Similarly that's how you transfer data to and from a phone through a USB cable, in binary.

However, data seems to be very well contained in the DS. In theory, could you transfer the data through a USB cable from the charging port? What about through either of the game ports? And how would you know ahead of time if a "port" is only in, only out, or bidirectional?

All DS lite capture cards that I've seen work at a more fundamental level. They seem to intercept the video flex cable directly. But that means opening up the DS which I'm trying to avoid.[image]

And how would I learn more about the theory behind what this is all about? Thank you!

Comment: This is very unclear and far too broad. A few drawn arrows are not useful info, we would need to see the circuit board in order to give any meaningful answer. Generally you "reverse-engineer" products by looking at integrated circuits and traces on the PCB, as well as measure signals with an oscilloscope.

Comment: I doesn't make sens. if there is no such data on that ports already what would be transfer it? A special modified game? Still doesn't make sens... Processor doesn't have access to video output signal...

Comment: Basically you are looking for a way to exfiltrate data?

Comment: It depends what kind of things the port is connected to. If it's connected to the processor's data bus then it can probably send and receive data. If it's connected to the charging circuit it's probably good for charging. Connectors are just easy ways to attach wires to other wires, so real question appears to be *how do I tell what a wire does?*

Comment: or maybe *how do I guess what the wires in a certain connector do?*

Comment: and the only answer is probably *learn about how these kinds of systems work*. For the DS in particular, there is a well-known document called "GBAtek" that is basically an unofficial datasheet with all kinds of useful info about the DS and Gameboy Advance.

Comment: there is another way.  you could point a camera at the screen.

Comment: If you were designing a DS, would you send the video data out any of the ports? No you would not. *Unless* there was some good reason for that - maybe one that didn't ever actually happen - like maybe you wanted to be able to plug an external screen into one of the ports.

Comment: For Gameboy slot, "data seems to only go one way - into the DS lite." Is false. The GBA cartridge has a full fledged memory bus, which is already well documented at GameBoy modding and enthusiast sites.

Comment: @nanofarad likewise the DS slot is also a full-fledged serial bus (comparable to SATA, I guess, but not as advanced)

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic method for figuring out how a port behaves or how to get data out of a port. What a port does is determined by what component the port is connected to internally, and what other components that component is connected to, and how all of those components are configured. Figuring out what is possible with a DS Lite, and what is not possible, could turn out to be a monumental task.

One method for trying to figure out what a port does is to consult the manufacturer's documentation for the device. However, for a consumer product like the DS Lite, it's very unlikely that the documentation will say anything about how to use the device in such an unusual way.

Another method is to learn the details of how the device works from a software perspective. Can you find out what kind of firmware the device runs? Has anyone ever discovered a debugging interface and then documented it? You might be able to find an answer that way.

One more method is to physically open the device up and look at what ports are connected to what components. If you know enough about digital circuit design, you may be able to figure out the function of each port.

Needless to say, any of the above methods is probably going to be a huge amount of work. Look online to find out what other people have already figured out and what techniques they used.

And keep in mind that what you're trying to do may turn out to just be impossible. If the video signal isn't connected to any of the ports, then it probably just isn't possible to get a video signal out through the ports without physically modifying the hardware.

All in all, the easiest way to get a video signal out of the device is almost certainly going to be to open it up and intercept the video cable.